# How can I get my C# and MySql to return more than one entry from the database?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, search

This is an excerpt from my code. Everything works the way it's supposed to, but I'm trying to add a feature which allows the program to return more than one row from the database - that is to say, more than one result.

If I search for "silver", I get Silverado; if I search "silver l", I get Silver Linings Playbook.

What I've been *trying* to get it to do is to search for "silver" and get Silverado AND Silver Linings Playbook, but my loops haven't fixed the issue and some help would be...helpful.

```
            movieBox.Items.Clear();
            try
            {
            db_connection.Open();
            sql_command = new MySqlCommand("select * from mov_db.movies where title like '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'", db_connection);
            sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
            if (sql_reader.Read())
                {
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("title"));
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("year"));
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("genre"));
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("rating"));
                }
            else
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but that title is unavailable.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use a while loop instead of an if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not looping through all the rows that were returned by your reader, instead you're just reading the first one. Here's how to fix it:

```
movieBox.Items.Clear();
try
{
    db_connection.Open();
    sql_command = new MySqlCommand("select * from mov_db.movies where title like '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'", db_connection);
    sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
    if(sql_reader.HasRows)
        while(sql_reader.Read())
        {
            movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("title"));
            movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("year"));
            movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("genre"));
            movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("rating"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but that title is unavailable.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nas, that got it going!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a while loop like:

```
movieBox.Items.Clear();
            try
            {
            db_connection.Open();
            sql_command = new MySqlCommand("select * from mov_db.movies where title like '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'", db_connection);
            sql_reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
            while (sql_reader.Read())
                {
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("title"));
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("year"));
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("genre"));
                movieBox.Items.Add(sql_reader.GetString("rating"));
                }
            if(movieBox.Items.Count() == 0)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but that title is unavailable.");
                }
            }
```

This is untested but it's probably very close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop instead of an if.
Reader.Read will return true if there are any more records for the reader to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `while` loop instead of an `if`. Also, I see you have a `movieBox` variable, which has an `Items` field where you add the columns of the result. However, you need more instances of records to return in your method and therefore you need to create a `movieBox` in each iteration in your while loop, but add that to a `movieBoxes` variable, which represents a `Collection` of `movieBox` elements and return `movieBoxes` instead of `movieBox` after the `while` loop.